# Laravel Nova dependsOn function does not work properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In this case

```
        $fields[] = Select::make('Auto renewal domain', 'domainAM')
                ->dependsOn(['domainId'], function ($field, $request, $formData) {
                    if ($formData->domainId <= 0 ) $field->hide();
                })
                ->options([0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'])
                ->rules([($request->domainId > 0) ? 'required' : ''])
                ->onlyOnForms();
```

when I edit item in field domainAM I do not see value from database.
But when I comment dependsOn I see it.

Who knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of nova?

Comment: I use laravel 10 and nova 4.22.2